# Run a joomla project from from tar

Tags: joomla, zip, tar

I got a joomla project in tar and I'm trying to run it locally. I imported the db , extracted the files in the htdocs folder(using lampp) and made modified the configuration file with no luck. Anyone with any ideas?
Thanx!

Comment: Can you describe 'no luck' in detail please? What do you see if you open the initial URL in the browser?

Comment: `Fatal error: Class 'JConfig' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/joomla/includes/framework.php on line 49` is what I got.

Comment: Which Joomla version is this? A tree structure of your folders would be helpful as well.